# Facebook Graph OAuthException - #2500 Unknown path components error when fetching page posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unknown path components: /$PAGE_ID,
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500
}
```

I got the error above after trying to fetch a page posts using C# Facebook SDK 7.0.6

Here is my Request.

```
var downloadPostsTask = fb.GetTaskAsync(@"/" + PageId + @"?fields=posts{type,description,name,full_picture,source,caption,link,status_type,message}", ctsToken);
```

and

```
var downloadPostsTask = fb.GetTaskAsync(PageId + @"?fields=posts{type,description,name,full_picture,source,caption,link,status_type,message}", ctsToken);
```

both are resulting same error

How to solve this problem? I tried to search but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by explicitly specifying Graph API Version in the Facebook object

```
var fb = new FacebookClient
                {
                    AccessToken = token,
                    IsSecureConnection = true,
                    Version = "v2.6"
                };
```

Comment: I was trying with postman to get data and my path was .../2.9/.. and I had problem with unknown path components..I just needed .../v2.9/... and problem was solved.